# Java print top view of binary search tree

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

Question given: Given a pointer to the root of a binary tree, print the top view of the binary tree.
The tree as seen from the top the nodes, is called the top view of the tree.

This is the code I have written for top view of tree.
My code is running for some cases only . I want to know what is wrong in the code that I have written .

My concept was that to give index to each node and only first node that gets a particular index will be printed .

```
 public static void rhs(Node root,int index,ArrayList list){
        if(root==null){
            return;
        }
        for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            if (index==list.get(i)){
               rhs(root.left,index-1,list);
               rhs(root.right,index+1,list);
               return;
            }
        }
         System.out.print(root.data+" ");
                list.add(index);
                rhs(root.left,index-1,list);
                rhs(root.right,index+1,list); 
    }

public static void topView(Node root) {
    if (root==null){
        return;
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(0);
 
    System.out.print(root.data+" ");

    rhs(root.left,-1,list);
  
    rhs(root.right,1,list);         


}
```

One of the case it wasn't working for was -

```
15
1 14 3 7 4 5 15 6 13 10 11 2 12 8 9
```

ouput expected (sequence doesn't matter):

```
2 1 14 15 12
```

my output:

```
1 14 2 6 12
```

already predefined which cannot be changed-

```
public static Node insert(Node root, int data) {
        if(root == null) {
            return new Node(data);
        } else {
            Node cur;
            if(data <= root.data) {
                cur = insert(root.left, data);
                root.left = cur;
            } else {
                cur = insert(root.right, data);
                root.right = cur;
            }
            return root;
        }
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = scan.nextInt();
    Node root = null;
    while(t-- > 0) {
        int data = scan.nextInt();
        root = insert(root, data);
    }
    scan.close();
    topView(root);
}
```

}

Comment: How should the input be mapped to a binary tree?

Comment: hey! I made the changes in my question please check. Insertion of node was already given to me which I cannot change !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it assumes that when you get to a certain index the *first* time, that this will also be with the value that will be visible from the top. This surely is true *at that moment*, but it could happen that a node that is visited *later* might end up at the same index, *and* be higher up in the tree, therefore hiding the previously visible node.

Here is a small example:

```
index:   -1  0  1

tree:        4
            / \
           1   5
            \
             2
              \
               3
```

For this tree, your algorithm will first process the left sub tree of the root, and so it will visit 3 *before* 5, and so you'll output "3" for index 1.

So, to fix this, you should actually refrain from outputting anything, until you have traversed the whole tree. While traversing associate a value and depth with each index (using a Map maybe), and update the associated value when you have a new candidate with a lesser depth value.

Comment: oooohh , Now I finally get it ! Thanks a lot for your help otherwise I would have thought I missed some special case . Thanks for clearing my concept !!! I really appreciate it

Comment: You're welcome. Note that you can only mark one answer as accepted though.

Comment: oh Sorry , I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Java program to print top
// view of binary tree
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.TreeMap;
 
// class to create a node
class Node {
    int data;
    Node left, right;
 
    public Node(int data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        left = right = null;
    }
}
 
// class of binary tree
class BinaryTree {
    Node root;
 
    public BinaryTree() { root = null; }
 
    // function should print the topView of
    // the binary tree
    private void TopView(Node root)
    {
        class QueueObj {
            Node node;
            int hd;
 
            QueueObj(Node node, int hd)
            {
                this.node = node;
                this.hd = hd;
            }
        }
        Queue<QueueObj> q = new LinkedList<QueueObj>();
        Map<Integer, Node> topViewMap
            = new TreeMap<Integer, Node>();
 
        if (root == null) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            q.add(new QueueObj(root, 0));
        }
 
        System.out.println(
            "The top view of the tree is : ");
 
        // count function returns 1 if the container
        // contains an element whose key is equivalent
        // to hd, or returns zero otherwise.
        while (!q.isEmpty()) {
            QueueObj tmpNode = q.poll();
            if (!topViewMap.containsKey(tmpNode.hd)) {
                topViewMap.put(tmpNode.hd, tmpNode.node);
            }
 
            if (tmpNode.node.left != null) {
                q.add(new QueueObj(tmpNode.node.left,
                                   tmpNode.hd - 1));
            }
            if (tmpNode.node.right != null) {
                q.add(new QueueObj(tmpNode.node.right,
                                   tmpNode.hd + 1));
            }
        }
        for (Entry<Integer, Node> entry :
             topViewMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.print(entry.getValue().data);
        }
    }
 
    // Driver Program to test above functions
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        /* Create following Binary Tree
            1
        / \
        2 3
        \
            4
            \
            5
            \
                6*/
        BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree();
        tree.root = new Node(1);
        tree.root.left = new Node(2);
        tree.root.right = new Node(3);
        tree.root.left.right = new Node(4);
        tree.root.left.right.right = new Node(5);
        tree.root.left.right.right.right = new Node(6);
        System.out.println(
            "Following are nodes in top view of Binary Tree");
        tree.TopView(tree.root);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your reply . But what are the changes I should make in my code ? what mistakes did I make in my code?

Comment: if that would have been the case then it wouldn't have worked at all . But it is working and giving correct outputs too

Comment: that may well be a coincidence.

Comment: Can you explain then what do you mean by "everything" then ? because coincidence can be for 1 or 2 cases only

Comment: So firstly even though you print node only if it is the first one with the index, it does not mean it will be a correct one. Your recursion function expands each branch and not each level. Secondly, the fact that you have two functions that do exact same thing and just have different name is useles. Thirdly, you dont have to use a list to check indexes. All you need is range as binary tree will always extend only by one to either side.

Comment: thats why you have to change ewerithing, because aproach is wrong from its core

Comment: oh okay . Thanks a lot for your time and effort ! I really appreciate it :)